# SQL error: subquery returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this same question is asked more than a few times, but I think my case is a bit more complicated.

So I have the following table:

```
table_element_element
---------------------------------------------------
| fk_source | sourcetype | fk_target | targettype |
---------------------------------------------------
| 12325     | order      | 11111     | invoice    |
| 12325     | order      | 2652      | shipping   |
---------------------------------------------------

table_expedition
-----------------------------
| rowid     | ref           |
-----------------------------
| 2652      | SHIP2201-1225 |
-----------------------------
```

Now, what I am trying to do is get a list of invoices (easy) and then, based on the invoice ID get the shipping REF.

I have the following query:

```
(SELECT e.ref FROM table_expedition e 
WHERE 
e.rowid = (SELECT ee.fk_target FROM table_element_element ee
           WHERE ee.sourcetype = 'commande'
           AND ee.targettype = 'shipping'
           AND ee.fk_source = (SELECT ee2.fk_source FROM table_element_element ee2
                              WHERE ee2.fk_target = f.rowid
                              AND ee2.sourcetype = 'commande'
                              AND ee2.targettype = 'facture'
                              )
          )
) as shipping_ref
```

In this case, `f.rowid` is the ID of the invoice.

If I make it a hard value (i.e. 11111) I get the shipping ref for this invoice correct. But obviously, it's the same for all invoices. However, when I set it as `f.rowid` I have the above-mentioned error.

Also important is, that this is just a part of a bigger query. That's why everything is within ()

**Clarification:**

In the query, if I change `WHERE ee2.fk_target = f.rowid` with `WHERE ee2.fk_target = 11111` I get the correct result i.e. `ref: SHIP2201-1225`

If I use it in the query as it is: I get the error 'Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: Either do JOIN's instead. Or switch = to IN.

Comment: Please update your question so that the sample data and the SQL match and provide the result you want to see based on your sample data. Your SQL uses source/target type values that are not present in your sample data - so anyone trying to run your SQL against your data is not going to get a result

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging, I've found a solution and learned something new: instead of giving an alias, you may also apply a number after the table name thus joining the same table twice. As a result, following query works like a charm:

```
Select
    table_facture.ref As facture_ref,
    table_expedition.ref As expedition_ref
From
    table_facture 
    Inner Join table_element_element On table_facture.rowid = table_element_element.fk_target 
    Inner Join table_commande On table_element_element.fk_source = table_commande.rowid 
    Inner Join table_element_element table_element_element1 On table_commande.rowid = table_element_element1.fk_source 
    Inner Join table_expedition On table_element_element1.fk_target = table_expedition.rowid
Where
    table_element_element.sourcetype = 'commande' And
    table_element_element.targettype = 'facture' And
    table_element_element1.sourcetype = 'commande' And
    table_element_element1.targettype = 'shipping'
```